# Add a publications section to CV

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, jobs

One section that I noticed is missing on the CV, is a section for publications. Granted the "Projects and Links" section could be used for this purpose, it would be nice to have a bit of isolation between a listing of publications that you have written or co-authored and the projects that you have worked on.

Comment: Related Suggestion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25294/build-your-own-cv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An articles section was added to Careers.

Comment: I might be missing somthing, but I think this only allows linking to online articles.  It would be useful to be able to cite physical media articles as well (Title, Publication, Co-authors, etc)

Comment: I support the comment of @JasonBirch. Besides articles, patents should be included as well.